# Not able to use query results inside Javascript UDF in Snowflake

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Thankyou for your time.

I am working on a problem in Snowflake database. I am basically trying to create a Javascript UDF like following -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getACity()   
RETURNS STRING   
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT   
AS 
'function getCity() {
var str;
$$  str = select * from CITY where name="Laflin" //This is the problem 
$$
return str;   
}';
```

As you can see I am trying to use data from another table in my function, but its not happening and I get following error -

> JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected
>   identifier in getACity at ' str = select * from CITY where
>   name="Laflin"' position 21

I understand the syntax I am using to execute a query inside a javascript function is not correct, but I am not even sure if it is possible in Snowflake.

I have following questions -

1. Can I execute a query inside a javascript UDF and use the results in ongoing function ?
2. Can I call a Javascript UDF inside another Javascript UDF ? If this is possible it will work for me as well.

I have gone through Snowflake [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-function.html) but could not find any help specific to this case.

Thankyou again for your time. Much appreciated !

Answer (score 3):

To answer your questions:

- Snowflake JavaScript UDFs do not allow executing queries inside them in any form today.
- you can not use JS UDFs in ther JS UDFs

You CAN use SQL UDFs for that, but that can only produce one column, e.g.

```
create or replace function getcityid() 
returns string as '
  select id from CITY where name='Laflin'
';
```

Or use VIEWs, e.g.

```
create or replace view cities as select * from CITY where name='Laflin'
```

If you explain *exactly* what you try to achieve, this should help.

Also, note that `"Laflin"` in SQL refers to a column named `Laflin`, not to a string with a value `Laflin`. Use `'Laflin'` for that.

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake JavaScript UDF do not support to run sql however you can use procedure to do that however procedure will only return one value/not the table function result.

For details about the Snowflake please refer the documentation

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-overview.html#benefits-of-stored-procedures